# a more efficient 'if' statement for multiple options

Tags: c#, if-statement

I wonder if anyone has some ideas to make the following shorter and more efficient. I have 3 dropdowns where a user selects lower age limit, upper age limit and gender. They can select as many as they want, even none. I then have an if statement that will do a process based on what they select.  Assume l, u and g are the parameters that are passed.

```
if((age > l && age < u && gender == g)
|| (age > l && age < u && g == null)
|| (age > l && u == null && g == null)
|| (age < u && gender == g && l == null)
|| (age < u ...etc etc)
```

Is there a better way of forming this rather then a tedious if statement?

Comment: without knowing the real logic it's hard to be concrete - but yes, there will be better ways. Switch might be better for you. You could use methods for various cases to encapsulate logic better etc.

Comment: Are `l`, `u`, and `g` `int?`s?

Comment: Simplify the logic first. For example why have two separate lines to check for gender or null, when you can write `&& (g==gender or g==null)` ? This is straightforward logic algebra

Comment: Why would you want to make it more efficient? Shorter I can understand, but more efficient? I think you are micro optimizing.

Comment: For the future: such questions are better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ok thanks Xan, I didn't know about code review until now. If I may ask, what sort of questions go here vs code review?

Comment: My thoughts would be SO is more for how to solve the problem, Code Review is more for better ways to write your code. Example here is you've already solved your problem which is returning True / False based on upper / lower age and gender, so you aren't trying to solve a problem just do it nicer / better. That's my take on it anyway, seems like it could be a fine line in some cases.

Comment: ok cool, thanks Ryan

Comment: BMills, for more info, check on the Help Center on "What topics can I ask about here?" http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can make it more readable by creating a variable for each condition.

```
var lowerAgeLimitMet = (l == null || age > l);
var upperAgeLimitMet = (u == null || age < u);
var genderLimitMet = (g == null || gender == g);
if(lowerAgeLimitMet && upperAgeLimitMet && genderLimitMet)
{
    //Do work here
}
```

Comment: a good solution, thanks.

Comment: I prefer this solution to the accepted answer because it makes the code a lot more readable and maintanable.

Comment: It also makes it easier, if you need to, to tell the user which condition(s) they _haven't_ met.

Comment: Simplicity and maintainability over code size!

Comment: I'd go a step further and rename l as lowerAgeLimit, u as upperAgeLimit and g as gender. Why use 1 letter variables, are you worried you'll wear out your keyboard or run out of letters?

Comment: I had a JavaScript back-end full of business rules (approximately 40) for a particular resource update action. Before the case statements started, I had about 30 lines of code that simply declared aptly-named variables for the case statements. **This is by far the most readable and maintainable solution.** I looked back on that code 2 years later and it only took me 5 minutes to get back up to speed on all of the logic that was happening.

Comment: Ryan I do have different variable names in my code, just wanted to make the question as simple as possible for here.  I have changed this to the accepted answer based on the comments and number of upvotes.

Answer (score 8):

That should work:

```
if((age > l || l == null) && (age < u || u == null) && (gender == g || g == null))
   ...
```

Comment: Well as C# is lazy, and if you use int? types, this code require a bit of refactoring...

Comment: yes this is exactly it, thanks!  I forgot to specify that I'm using 'int', not 'int?', so I'll just substitute '0' for null for the ages and all will be good.

Comment: Why is this more efficient? I think the C# compiler already optimizes this.

Comment: Also, since the conditions are evaluated left-to-right, I would put the null-checks left. Like this: `(l == null || age > l) && (u == null || age < u) && (g == null || gender == g)`. Again, the C# compiler might optimize this too.

Comment: Maarten it's more efficient because it's just 1 line instead of the 9 I previously had!

Comment: You may want to be careful of your use of the word 'efficient' which has a very specific meaning when it comes to programming. I'm not saying you are wrong here (You've decreased the comparisons (i.e. age > l) which is the important part (not lines) so it IS more efficient) but as @Maarten has eluded the compiler likely already adjusts your code to make it more efficient so asking 'How can I make this more efficient' will often be met with replies of 'You don't have to!' or 'Why?' Looks to me like you really just want the code shorter and more compact, efficiency isn't really a factor!

Comment: @BMills - that has literally nothing to do with efficiency. You can format your entire program as just one line if you'd like.

Comment: @Davor It *is so* more efficient: far less head-scratching is involved!

Comment: This would be the correct answer if the problem with the OP's code was inefficiency rather than readability.  However the problem was the latter, and micro-optimization at this level is unlikely to make a noticeable impact on performance.  I strongly prefer Synvert's solution, as it solves the actual problem with the code, even if that wasn't necessarily the problem that OP identified.

Comment: I understand the question as: how can I reformat the complex logical expression in an easier way; and I tried to answer the question according to that. Of course there are many ways to getter better code; you should use self-explaining variable names; you should break complex statements in shorter ones; you should use comments; you should make your code readable by using indenting and empty lines. But that was not the topic of the question. (Nevertheless I would admit to Marteen to turn around the statements.)

Comment: @nocomprende - efficiency means it uses fewer CPU cycles to perform its calculations. I get that you're trying to be funny, but conflating readability and efficiency, two extremely common CS terms is as funny as pretending that 2 + 2 = 5 in math classes. Meaning it's not funny at all, you just make yourself look like like you have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Davor I was making the point that readability is more important than trying to outguess the compiler optimizer or the CPU, or the thousands of people who worked on those things. Thought-time is now more costly than cpu cycles (it was not always so, before I was born). I have been studying computer programming since 1978, and you are correct, I have no idea what I am talking about. Eventually, you will get there too. Just give it time. It is not funny until it is all funny. Some day, writing programs by hand will be about as common as making your own arrows. That day will surely come.

Comment: @nocomprende - yes, that is all fine and dandy, condescension, after all, is a typical trait of old people, but you are still using the wrong word.

Comment: @Davor Gosh, I was only trying to be funny.

Answer (score 2):

Define `lowerLimit` as `int.MinValue`, `upperLimit` as `int.MaxValue` and let `g` be `null`.

Then this will handle all the cases:

```
int lowerLimit;
if (!int.TryParse(dropdown.Text, out lowerLimit))
{
    lowerLimit = int.MinValue;
}
int upperLimit;
if (!int.TryParse(dropdown.Text, out upperLimit))
{
    upperLimit = int.MaxValue;
}
// Same checks for gender
if(age > lowerLimit  && age < upperLimit  && (g== null || gender == g))
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: this won't won't work as they might just select the gender dropdown and leave the age dropdowns null

Comment: Alternatively - you don't need to specify a variable for `lowerlimit` and `upperLimit` - the Int Structure already has `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue` 

so..

`if(age > int.MinValue && age < int.MaxValue  && (g== null || gender == g))
{
    // Your code here
}`

Comment: @BMills so your real problem is how to deal with arbitrary criteria, *not* how to simplify a logical expression. Expressions, fluent interfaces, LINQ etc are possible solutions to your real problem.

Comment: @BMills ok, does the edit satisfy your needs ?

Comment: sorry Thomas, I should have specified I already have the dropdowns have been parsed to int. So more accurately my statement should be saying '0' instead of 'null' for the age parameters.  Unfortunately your solution will still restrict some scenarios I don't want restricted.

Answer (score 0):

If we are playing code golf:

```
if (age > (l ?? int.MinValue) && age < (u ?? int.MaxValue) && gender == (g ?? gender))
```

Edit: Fixed variable order per comments

Comment: If l, u and g are the parameters that can be nulll, shouldnt it be `age > (l ?? int.MinValue) && age < (u ?? int.MaxValue) && gender == (g ?? gender)`?

Comment: You are right, my brain flip-flopped them for some reason.   I have corrected my post.